# Enterprise Integration Pattern Solution drawing tool

Tags: soa, apache-camel, esb, enterprise-integration

I would like to know whether there any drawing tools available to map a given use case solution in terms of EIPs. There is a stencil available for MS Visio and a SVG alternative for OpenOffice. The shapes in the stencil is good but does not seem like the best graphics for a presentation. Any alternatives available for drawing EIPs?

Comment: I found a comment somewhere (on the Internet) that the biggest problem with using Visio for these sorts of drawings is that the default font size is inappropriate. But you can select everything and pick a font size that shows up well on the projector image.

Comment: More important than the quality or "what is best" regarding the images is in your understanding of the solution you are proposing and ability to convey that to the audience. Understand the audience and truly communicate and you can use scribbled boxes and lines scanned off a napkin.

Comment: @LeeMeador - Appreciate your feedback, but working with the stencils provided by Vision is actually annoying specially if you don't own one. Regardless I ended up using Visio and I do agree with you that its up to me and my presentation skills to make the audience understand my solution. Great drawing tools does help :) Cheerz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Btw you could automate that. Check this:

http://camel.apache.org/visualisation.html

Use camel:dot maven goal

Answer (score 6):

[diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/?splash=0&libs=eip) has a set of EIP stencils built-in. I'm not sure if it addresses the issues in the question, but the tool is [free](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio). (I'm a developer on the project).

[[image: EIP stencil set in draw.io]]

Answer (score 2):

I've created an OmniGraffle EIP stencil years ago for the book Spring Integration in Action. I pushed it to Graffletopia, but I cannot find it there quickly. Let me know if you are interested in the OmniGraffle stencil and I'll search a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the stencils? Those are simply the shapes presented in the book Enterprise Integration Patterns. Looking at a presentation from the author of the book, I don't think the shapes look bad in presentation: http://www.eaipatterns.com/docs/jaoo_hohpeg_enterpriseintegrationpatterns.pdf.

I am not aware of any tools to draw EIP scenarios other than say Visio, Open Office Draw or similar tools. There are some IDEs to create routes (Fuse IDE and Talend Open Studio for instance), but these are really just to create runnable EIP implementations, not for presentation.

Comment: Just to follow up on this answer from @petter, the EAI Patterns book site has the visio stencils for download at http://www.eaipatterns.com/downloads.html

Comment: I think that was even mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but [Lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com/) (online cloud-based diagram tool) has an Enterprise Integration Pattern stencil, too.